# Migrations not creating all fields from class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5. When creating a new migration it is generating the some tables correctly. However, classes like the one below are being generated with almost all of the fields missing in migration script.

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Meeting Topic")]
    public string MeetingTopic;   

    [Display(Name = "Meeting Minutes")]
    public int MeetingMinutes;

    public ICollection<MeetingTopic> MeetingTopics { get; set; } = new HashSet<MeetingTopic>();

    [Display(Name = "Meeting Documents")]
    public ICollection<MeetingDocuments> MeetingDocuments { get; set; } = new   HashSet<MeetingDocuments>();

    [Display(Name = "Meeting Notes")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "100 characters limit.")]
    public string MeetingNotes { get; set; }
}
```

The SQL table create script being created from the migration which is missing all the field except for MeetingNotes

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Meeting",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                MeetingNotes = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 100, nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Meeting", x => x.ID);
            });
```

So far I've tried deleting all migrations and even the database and rebuilding but the new migration still return the same table with missing fields.

If anyone has any idea of what could be causing it would be very helpful. Thanks